# how to insert getdate function using vba

Tags: database, vba

i want to retrieve date from sql server not from system. so i use getdate function but it not working in vba [here is code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGHWT.png)

```
 conn.Execute "insert into dbo.Customers (AccountNo,Amount,code) values ('" & AccountNo & "', '" & Amount & "', '" & getdate() & "')"
```

Comment: thanks lot  Mitch Wheat

Comment: are you there Mitch Wheat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `getdate()` to be executed by SQL Server, not VBA. You have quotes in the wrong place around `getdate()`:

```
conn.Execute "insert into dbo.Customers (AccountNo, Amount, code) values ('" & AccountNo & "', '" & Amount & "', getdate())"
```